# Electrical impedance tomography and MCMC

Tags: python, matlab, bayesian, mcmc

I want to use metropolis Hastings sampler to estimate the interior cavity of a body.  I have already used the forward model which is method of fundamental solution to estimate the potential and current flux values (data).  I am having difficulty estimating the the cavity or radius using the Bayesian method (mcmc). Can someone help me with how I can? approach this because I am new to the MCMC

Comment: Please provide some of the code you already have. This seems to be quite specific.

Answer (score 0):

Solving an inverse problem is a big topic that requires you to understand non-linear optimization, ill-posed problems, regularization and lots of experience with experiments and data processing (especially data calibration). It is not something can just hand to you a solution unless you spend years, or at least semesters of study by taking courses and doing real projects.

There are tons of books, dissertations and literature on EIT image reconstruction. Most of these approaches are shared among other model-based inverse problems such as diffuse optical tomography (DOT), microwave tomography (MWT) etc. If you are interested, you can see many of the basic methods in my [thesis on microwave tomography](http://fanglab.org/publication/thesis/Qianqian_Fang_PhD_Dissertation_2004.pdf), especially Part I. The inverse algorithm used is almost the same as EIT, the only difference is the forward solver.